# Is there a proper way to read input from a StringStream

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stringstream

I am writing a custom bash that executes commands in a serial and parallel fashion. When I try and echo anything out to the terminal, there is a space that becomes appended to the end of my line and it makes me fail a test case. There error is in my process command method:

```
Commands commandProcess(std::string line, bool parallel, bool single) {
   // Create a list of commands to be returned if there
   // is processing occurring.
   Commands list; // vector of strings
   // Set up a string stream to read the line
   std::stringstream ss(line);
   std::string cl = ""; // clean line
   // While the string stream is still has unread info read
   // through quotes and assign the commands to a list.
   std::string temp = "";
   while (ss >> std::quoted(temp)) {
       cl += temp + " ";
       list.push_back(temp);
   }
   boost::trim_right(cl);
   std::cout << "Running: " << cl << std::endl;
   // Run a one line argument
   if (!parallel && single) {
       ChildProcess cp;
       cp.forkNexec(list);
       std::cout << "Exit code: " << cp.wait() << std::endl;
   }
   return list;
}
```

Everything works fine in my program besides the echo command. Any guidance is extremely appreciated.

[image: expectedoutput]

Comment: Maybe you're supposed to delete the space, or in general any trailing spaces.

Comment: Could this be a cr/lf issue, where that extra space is the result of an extra carriage-return somewhere in the processing?

Comment: By the way, you should post text, not pictures of text, so that us readers can cut and paste.

Comment: After further thought, it doesn't look like a cr/lf issue, because the lines quoted with single quotes don't have it. Clearly there's something about double quotes going on, and that means something related to your use of std::quote might be suspect. But what seems strange is I thought std::quote would remove the double quotes in that case, but you show them in your output. Is something in ChildProcess::forkNexec putting those quotes back? And if so, it is maybe putting back a space at the end?